# jQuery variables scope undefined after form submit

Tags: jquery

I am grabbing a data attribute on click for the id that I want to post, If I console.log() my id IO can see it, however I then have a submit function for the form and the data is undefined here... Not sure why, here is my code:

```
$('[data-id="add_child_notification"]').unbind().bind('click', function(){

    var data = [];
    var message;
    var parent_id;
    var user_id;

    parent_id  = $(this).attr('data-parent-id');

    user_id = $(this).attr('data-user-id');

    data.push({ name: 'parent_id', value : parent_id, nameUid: 'user_id', valueUid : user_id });

    console.log('before: '+parent_id);

    $('[data-form="send_child_notification"]').unbind().bind('submit', function(){

        console.log('after: '+data[1].parent_id);

        message = $('[data-input="child-message-textarea"]:last').val();

        console.log('msg: '+message);

        data.push({ nameMsg: 'message', valueMsg: message });

        $.post(URL+'notifications/send_child_notification', data, function(e){

        if(e.status){

            $('body').append('<div class="success_box"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span><p>Notification sent</p></div>');
                $('.success_box').delay(1000).fadeOut();
                window.location = window.location.href;
            } else {
                alert(e);
                //alert('Uh oh! Something went wrong, please try again..');
            }

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: You never assigned anything to `data.parent_id` so it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an array that contains objects.

```
data == [ {name: 'parent_id', value : parent_id, name: 'user_id', value : user_id } ]
```

So you have to use `data[0].value`, which value is `parent_id`.

**EDIT 1 :**

As James noticed, the "value" key is defined twice, so the last time it's defined overrides the previous one(s) and you'll get `user_id`.

For that matter, "name" is also defined twice.

In other words, there's a flaw in your design and you can't reach `parent_id`. Correct the double keys definiton with something like :

```
data.push({ name: 'parent_id', value : parent_id, uidName : 'user_id', uidValue : user_id })
```

**EDIT 2 :**

Actually, you're building an array of objects, but I see it's very clumsy and you don't really know where you're headed to. You're building something like this :

```
data == [ { name: 'parent_id', value : parent_id, nameUid: 'user_id', valueUid : user_id },
{ nameMsg: 'message', valueMsg: message } ]
```

...which is all but convenient and standard.
I guess you want this data object :

```
data == {
     'parent_id' : parent_id,
     'user_id' : user_id,
     'message' : message }
```

So you can access properties simply with `data.parent_id` or `data.message`.

If so, do this :

```
$('[data-id="add_child_notification"]').unbind().click( function(){

    var data = {
         'parent_id' : $(this).data('parent-id'),
         'user_id' : $(this).data('user-id')
    }

    $('[data-form="send_child_notification"]').unbind().submit( function(){

         data.message = $('[data-input="child-message-textarea"]:last').val();

         $.post(URL+'notifications/send_child_notification', data, function(e){

           ....
```

Also, selectors like `$('[data-input="child-message-textarea"]:last')` look really clumsy too, but since you didn't post any HTML code, it's hard to guess the right one and correct.

Comment: actually `data[0].value` will probably be `user_id` because the value property is listed twice.

Comment: if I try console.log('after: '+data[0].parent_id); I get undefined, If I try a key of 1 I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent_id' of undefined

Comment: Just console.log(data). What does it say?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) gives [{"name":"parent_id","value":"74","nameUid":"user_id","valueUid":"112"},{"nameMsg":"message","valueMsg":"asdfgasdffasdfasdf"}]
jquery-1.10.2.js:8706 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/web/timesheet/notifications/send_child_notification".

Comment: Yeah, drop it. It's too complicated and isn't going anywhere. See my Edit #2.

Answer (score 0):

I turned out to be nothing to do with scope instead what it was is I am declaring an object using jQuery and you can't push to an object. Instead you need to assign a var to an object like so:

```
data.user_id = user_id;
data.message = message;
```

After doing so my vars were defined properly and everything worked!

Thanks for the help!